# how to pass a value to from listview item control to another ObjectDataSource inside in the same place?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have to list views A,and B

listview B is inside listview A.

i want to pass some parameters from Listview A to Listview B's ObjectDataSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you mean to say that listview B is nested within A. So you can use data-binding expressions to pass values to nested controls. You may face issue in passing parameters - see [this](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2006/11/07/Binding-data-to-ObjectDataSource-parameters.aspx) article for work-around.

Here's the [article](http://leedumond.com/blog/nested-listviews-and-more-working-with-databound-controls-inside-the-listview/) that shows you nesting list views and supplying data by both using data-binding expression as well as using parent control's events in code-behind.